# separate values by numbers in excel sheet by java program

Tags: java, excel, collections

Hi, I have a excel sheet i need to separate values by numbers if the value of number changes it should come in next line  by [java](/questions/tagged/java) program

Example

```
    1234.456  hello.jsp
    1234.456  hello.jsp
    1234.457  hello.jsp
    1234.457  hello.jsp
    1234.459  hello.jsp
```

I need output as

```
    1234.456 hello.jsp,1234.456 hello.jsp
    1234.457 hello.jsp,1234.457 hello.jsp
    1234.459 hello.jsp
```

How can I separate the values and print in console? I tried

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook((fs));

        // Get first sheet from the workbook
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        Row row;
        Cell cell;

        // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
       int i=0;
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
        {
                row = rowIterator.next();

                // For each row, iterate through each columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                String value="";

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
                {
                cell = cellIterator.next();

                switch (cell.getCellType()) 
                {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        //pw.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+   "  ");

                    value=value+" ";
                    value=value+cell.getStringCellValue();

                    //System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+   "  ");
                //System.out.println();
                        break;

                }
                }
                strArray[i]=value;
                i++;
               //System.out.println();
               // pw.flush();

        }
        for(String tsr:strArray)
        System.out.println(tsr);
```

I am getting

```
    1234.456  hello.jsp
    1234.456  hello.jsp
    1234.457  hello.jsp
    1234.457  hello.jsp
    1234.459  hello.jsp
```

In Java, how do I now to separate it and print the values like the above output in the console?

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Get first sheet from the workbook
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        double pre=0.0,next=0.0;
        String valueStr = " ";
        for(Row row : sheet){
            if(row.getRowNum()==0){
                for (Cell cell : row) {
                    int i = cell.getColumnIndex();
                    switch (i) {
                    // column 0 
                    case 0:
                        pre = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                        break;
                    // column 1
                    case 1:
                        valueStr = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        System.out.print(pre+" "+valueStr+",");
                        break;
                    }
            }
            }else{
                for (Cell cell : row) {
                    int i = cell.getColumnIndex();
                    switch (i) {
                    // column 0
                    case 0:
                        next = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                        break;
                    // column 1
                    case 1:
                        valueStr = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        if(pre == next)
                            System.out.print(next+" "+valueStr+" ");
                        else
                            System.out.println();
                            System.out.print(next+" "+valueStr+",");
                        pre = next;
                        break;
                    }
                    }
            }
        }
```

Comment: hi Getting the error                                          Exception :Cannot get a numeric value from a text cell

Comment: I assume that your first cell is numeric one, you can change in switch case according to your way

Comment: I tried for two column see in switch cases,first column is numeric and second is string type, you can enhance it your own way.

Comment: my excel sheet will be like this  so i am getting same                              Client    Page     AccessDate      ProcessTime    Bytes
1234.456  hello.jsp  6/3/14 5:52 PM    4            1234
1234.456  hello.jsp  6/3/14 5:52 PM   6            234
1234.457  hello.jsp  6/3/14 5:52 PM   7            234
1234.457  hello.jsp  6/3/14 5:52 PM   8            234
1234.459  hello.jsp  6/3/14 5:52 PM   4             234

Comment: i am getting the same error like                                Exception :Cannot get a numeric value from a text cell

Comment: See your exception is due to accessing the numeric data in text column so do changes in switch cases according to data types, I don't have your code how can i figure out the cause of exception